# In how many languages is Null not equal to anything not even Null?

Tags: sql, ruby, oracle, language-agnostic, vb6

In how many languages is Null not equal to anything not even Null?

Comment: Not a language, but floating point NaN is also not equal to itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's this way in SQL (as a logic language) because null means unknown/undefined.

However, in programming languages (like say, C++ or C#), a null pointer/reference is a specific value with a specific meaning -- nothing.

Two nothings are equivilent, but two unknowns are not.  The confusion comes from the fact that the same name (null) is used for both concepts.

Comment: There **are** some programming languages with null-propagation. For instance VB.Net http://msmvps.com/blogs/bill/archive/2007/09/07/c-defies-logic.aspx

Answer (score 4):

In VB6 the expression `Null = Null` will produce `Null` instead of `True` as you would expect.
This will cause a runtime error if you try to assign it to a Boolean, however if you use it
as the condition of "`If ... Then`" it will act like `False`. Moreover `Null <> Null` will **also**
produce `Null`, so:

**In VB6 you could say that `Null` is neither equal to itself (or anything else), nor unequal!**

You're supposed to test for it using the `IsNull()` function.

VB6 also has other special values:

- `Nothing` for object references. `Nothing = Nothing` is a compile error. (you're supposed to compare it using "`is`")
- `Missing` for optional parameters which haven't been given. It has no literal representation so you can't even write `Missing = Missing`. (the test is `IsMissing(foo)`)
- `Empty` for uninitialized variables. This one does test equal to itself although there's **also** a function `IsEmpty()`.
- ... let me know if I've forgotten one

I remember being a bit disgusted with VB.

Comment: VB.Net has null propagation too. Null propagation is confusing, but if you're going to have nullable types at all, it's arguable that the cat is out of the bag, and you should propagate nulls. http://msmvps.com/blogs/bill/archive/2007/09/07/c-defies-logic.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Oracle is this way.

```
SELECT * FROM dual WHERE NULL=null;  --no rows returned
```

Comment: Actually, that is a property of SQL in general, it's not specific to Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has a null-safe equality operator, <=>, which returns true if both sides are equal or both sides are null.  See [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

Comment: +1 Interesting, but this should probably had been a comment on an SQL answer

Answer (score 2):

You can make ruby work that way:

```
class Null
 def self.==(other);false;end
end
n=Null
print "Null equals nothing" if n!=Null
```

Comment: @Hugh: Well, one might say that, but it *is* possible, which means people will do it... whether that's good or bad is another matter.

Comment: In ruby, null is called nil and NULL would not be defined giver the code posted. It is however perfectly possible to do what is implied here by typing: `class NilClass; def ==(o); false; end; end`

Comment: Wow @ormuriauga - you caught a 2 year old typo.  Fixed.  Now it does create a `Null` which is not equal to itself, as the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, Nullable<bool> has interesting properties with respect to logical operators, but the equality operator is the same as other types in that language (i.e., ((bool?)null == (bool?)null) == true).

To preserve the [short-circuited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) behavior of the short-circuited logical operators, and to preserve consistency with the non-short-circuited logical operators, the nullable boolean has some interesting properties. For example: true || null == true. false && null == false, etc. This stands in direct contradiction with other three-valued logic languages such as [ANSI SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization).

Comment: There's other interesting behaviours in C#. For some values of x and y `x==y` is true but `x<=y` is false. Which seems rather hard to defend. http://msmvps.com/blogs/bill/archive/2007/09/07/c-defies-logic.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you would have to do something like:

```
WHERE column is NULL
```

rather than

```
WHERE column = NULL
```