# Why nullable types will not be equal in this case?

Tags: c#, null

Surprisingly the code bellow will not succeed.

```
int? n1 = null;
int? n2 = null;
Assert.IsTrue(n1 <= n2);  // Fails here
```

Do you know why?

Comment: Your example may be better to ask why (null >= null) is false, bringing nullable into this makes it additionally more complex of a question, because now you need to discuss how you compare null to a non-nullable type.

Comment: meandmycode,  Good point.  I didn't realized that (null >= null) is false.  But looking deeper I realized that behind the scene CLR makes (null >= null) a nullable expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using boolean logic with null nullable values in C# (and VB.Net) often times defies logic.   I find the best way to make sense of it is to remember that "null is not a value".  Because null is not a value you cannot do any operations on it.  Hence things like "`1 > null`" and "`1 < null`" are both true.

Here is a detailed guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

If you do want to treat null as a value then you could use the GetValueOrDefaultMethod() to equate null with the default value.  For example

```
Assert.IsTrue(n1.GetValueOrDefault() <= n2.GetValueOrDefault());  // True
```

This is a bit verbose but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 4):

Either this is a typo and you meant "==" not "<=" or you misunderstand how nulls work.

In almost all languages (including c#) the only default legal operation on null is to check if something else is equal to it (in .Net == is by default reference equality).

<= and >= are not meaningful (as they would have very strange behaviour if they did)

Some languages (SQL being possibly the most well known) disallow the use of 'standard' equality operators to make this even more clear. in SQL null == null is NOT true, and a compliant server will refuse queries where you attempt to do this via a literal.

C# takes the same route as it's heritage (C style imperative languages) where the test for a null value is based on testing that the bits in it are zero (things get somewhat more complex but fundamentally that's what is happening). As such only reference types can truly be null (`Nullable<T>` has a lot of magic behind the scenes to make it look like it is but actually under the hood it *isn't null*). This means that the reference equality semantics follow nicely into null semantics, thus the == null is allowed.

Other languages implement null in a different fashion (for example SQL where anything can be made null thus the 'nullness' of something must be stored outside of it (much like Nullable). This means that the conventional use of equality need not be the primary concern and null can be truly special rather than a special case of certain types.
For further information on the specialness of null take a look at [This question has a list of such languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75267/in-how-many-languages-is-null-not-equal-to-anything-not-even-null/75314#75314)

Most reference types do not define a >= or <= operator so there is little problem in practice with the disconnect between == and <= (where normally if something is true for == it would be true for <= and >= as well).

Comment: Where this gets a bit confusing is C# vs. SQL. In programming languages like C#, null == null. But in SQL, nothing is true - NULL=NULL, NULL!=NULL, etc.

Comment: I want to assure you that this is not a typo.  I meant "<=".

Comment: Yes.  Null is 'special'.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75267/in-how-many-languages-is-null-not-equal-to-anything-not-even-null/75314#75314

Comment: Good points on the even tighter specialness constrains in many languages - integrating into answer...

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
int? n1 = null;
int? n2 = null;

// Test for equality
Assert.IsTrue((n1.HasValue && n2.HasValue && n1.Value == n2.Value) || (!n1.HasValue && !n2.HasValue));

// Test for less than or equal to
Assert.IsTrue(n1.HasValue && n2.HasValue && n1.Value <= n2.Value);
```

Comment: The original test was: n1.Value <= n2.Value

Answer (score 0):

Nullable types are wrapped into a System.Nullable object, so you don't compare the int value, you compare the reference. To compare the values, you need to make it like that:

```
Assert.IsTrue(n1.Value <= n2.Value);
```

I wrote a bit about nullable on my [blog](http://www.diskordia.ch/blog/?p=87).

Edit:
But in your case n1 and n2 is null, so you can't even compare the values.

Comment: It depends what you want to do, if one of these references is null. Let me assume null is also not valid, so it would look like this:
Assert.IsTrue(n1 != null && n2 != null && n1.Value <= n2.Value);

In my example it does not throw an exception if one of these references are null, because the condition is not checked entirely since it is false anyway.