# Why is this LINQ to EF query not working?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a problem with the following method:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> ListCustomers(int? parentId)
{
    Debug.Assert(parentId == null);
    //var list = _customerRepository.List().Where(c => c.ParentId == null);
    var list = _customerRepository.List().Where(c => c.ParentId == parentId);
    return list;
}
```

I have one Customer in my DB with a ParentId of null. When I call the method with `ListCustomers(null)`, `list` is empty for the return statement. If I swap the commented out line in and query with a hard-coded null, then list contains my one customer.

What could cause this difference between these two queries? Why is the one with `c.ParentId == parentId` not returning anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with nullable types you have to use it like this:

```
 .Where(c=> object.Equals(c.ParentId, parentId))
```

Comment: When `parentId` has a value, I get an EF `NotSupportedException` with this solution. Can anyone else confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

Becouse the Nullable type the linq provider will not generate the proper IS NULL check. See this answer for further information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/785501/1195510

Answer (score 1):

EF translates your query with `int?` to something like this:

```
DECLARE @parentId Int = null
SELECT ... WHERE ParentId = @parentId
```

When this is executed on the database, it doesn't do what you expect because in SQL `[column] = NULL` is always false.

I agree EF could handle this better, but as a workaround, you can write something like this:

```
.Where( c => !parentId.HasValue
  ? !c.ParentId.HasValue 
  : c.ParentId.Value == parentId.Value
)
```

EF will then generate a ( somewhat verbose ) SQL statement with the correct `IS NULL` predicates.